# Checking if linked list is a palindrome

Tags: java, linked-list, palindrome

```
public boolean palindromLinkedList() {
    //find size
    Node temp = head;
    int size=0;
    while(temp != null){
        size++;
        temp=temp.next;
    }
    //find while loop iteration
    int c;
    if(size%2 ==0){
        c = size/2;
    }else{
        c = (size+1)/2;
    }
    //intialise start and end pointer
    Node start = head;
    Node end = tail;
    //index pointer
    int k =size-1;
    //loop for the palindrome condition
    while(c > 0)`
        if(start.data != end.data){
            return false;
        }
        start = start.next;
        Node find = head;
        k--;
        for(int i=0;i<=k;i++){
            find = find.next;
        }
        end = find;
        c--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried to check if the linkedlist was a palindrome or not using an approach similar to two pointer.
I initialized two variables: `start = head` and `end = tail`.

Start checks the node from start and end starts from tail, after checking if data of start and end value are equal I made the changed made start point the next node and used a for loop to find the previous node of end, and this process continued until the pointer reach the middle node.

If the linkedlist is a palindrome it returns true or else false. I think my approach was correct, but there seems to be something that I missed.

Comment: Can you include the code for `Node`? In particular, what type is `Data`?

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a debugger? You can set breakpoints, and then execute the code one-line-at-a-time while monitoring variables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you implemented your own linked list, making this question hard to answer.

But, assuming your code is similar to java.util.LinkedList:

`==` in java checks references, not the Object given. You should use `.equals` to compare the Node data.
Even better would be `Objects.equals(start.data, end.data)` as it also handles `null`.

A great example for this behavior are Strings.
Java collects the strings that you hard-coded in your program, so it works sometimes, but most of the time it doesn't.

```java
"abc" == "abc" // true
"abc".equals("abc") // true
"abc" == new String("abc") // false
"abc".equals(new String("abc")) // true
"abc" == getUserPassword() // false
"abc".equals(getUserPassword()) // true if user enters abc
```

I would recommend you to implement a double linked list, as it will improve performance and in this case make your life a lot easier.
It's basically adding a reference to the previous node as well.
Therefore, you would not need to loop through all elements, but could get the previous node using `end.previous`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
```

This loop makes one iteration to many. Change to:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
```

This will solve the wrong outputs you get for even the most simple test cases.

But now you will hit another problem: this code is too slow. The repeated looping you have to do to determine the node that *precedes* `end` is too costly, and gives your implementation a O(²) time complexity. You'll need to come up with a better idea.

This problem has been solved multitudes of times before, and also on this site you'll find explanations of what the more efficient way is to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Side note:

> You should STORE the "size" variable as part of your linked list
> implementation, instead of calculating it with a loop. You know when
> anything is added to your linked list; add 1 to size. You know when
> something is deleted from your linked list; subtract 1 from size.

Main Response:

Without using an external structure such as a Stack, or converting your linked list to a doubly-linked list, you're going to have to repeatedly use loops to figure out the node at the "end" position.

You can REDUCE the number of iterations, though, by beginning at the "start" position and jumping forward the requisite number of times.

At the very first comparison, the "end" position will be `size - 1` jumps away from "start". After that, the number of jumps goes down by 2, every single time, since "start" has moved forward by one and "end" has moved backwards by one.

With that in mind, you can simply keep comparing as long as `(required number of jumps to get from "start" to "end" >= 1`.

That'd look something like this:

```
  public boolean palindromLinkedList() {
    // find size
    Node temp = head;
    int size = 0;
    while(temp != null){
        size++;
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    // check corresponding pairs
    Node end;
    Node start = head;
    int jumps = size - 1;
    
    while (jumps >= 1) {
      end = start;
      for(int i=1; i<=jumps; i++) {
        end = end.next;  
      }

      // ... do your comparison using one of the below ...
      
      // assuming a REFERENCE type of "data" that has an equals() method
      if (!start.data.equals(end.data)) {
        return false;
      }

      // assuming a PRIMITIVE type of "data" (like int, double, etc)
      if (start.data != end.data) {
        return false;
      }
      
      jumps = jumps - 2;
      start = start.next;
    }
    
    return true; // no counter-example found
  }
```